# BTL.BTFailure: not a valid bencoded string

Tags: python-2.7, bittorrent, tracker

I have been trying to use this python code http://blog.abhijeetr.com/2011/10/add-trackers-to-torrent-files-in-linux.html to automatticaly add certain public trackers to a torrent file.

After installing BitTorrent-bencode 5.0.8.1 and copying the "bencode.py"-file and "BTL.py" to the folder which contains my "add_tracker.py", "trackers.txt" & "Spaceman.2009.Xvid-VODO.mp4.torrent", I get the error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\a>cd C:\Users\a\Documents\python\lol

C:\Users\a\Documents\python\lol>add_tracker.py trackers.txt Spaceman.2009.Xvid-VODO.mp4.torrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\a\Documents\python\lol\add_tracker.py", line 22, in <module>
decoded_data = bencode.bdecode(torrent_file.read())
File "C:\Users\a\Documents\python\lol\bencode.py", line 68, in bdecode
raise BTFailure("not a valid bencoded string")
BTL.BTFailure: not a valid bencoded string

C:\Users\a\Documents\python\lol>
```

Alternatively I have also tried the old "bencode.py"-version given with the initial post given at: github /shadyabhi/Bencode-Torrent-Editor

They both hang at the same point.

Now my search so far has suggested it was due to corrupted torrents, to invalidate that I've tried hordes of different ones all yielding the same result, whilst evaluating them with torrenteditor.com.

On top of that, I can't completely/completely can't dissect the actual code of neither bencode.py nor add_tracker.py as was explained in different questions on here, concerning the use of the same scripts, for I lack the experience in python.

If anyone could tell me why this problem occurs, and what I could/should do to solve it I'd be rather gratefull :)

I'm sorry for the perhaps inconsistent layout.

Comment: do you have a link to that .torrent file?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is http://vodo.net/download/torrent/446 and is has been verified in three ways:

- tested it in a torrentprogram
- read in torrenteditor.com
- verified and used without this error in the orgininal code written by the creator*

*Full discussion here: http://blog.abhijeetr.com/2011/10/add-trackers-to-torrent-files-in-linux.html

On a side-note, I have already obtained my goal through other means, but I did not solve this error. For my understanding, and perhaps that of others I'm still curious if someone could point out why the error occurs. Especially since I litteraly copied the given codes, and followed procedure (as far as I can tell).